# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have recently moved to another machine and have had to check my project out from subversion again, but I am pretty sure this computer has Django 1.8 and the project is expecting 1.7.

I have tried to sync my db with the code to create the necessary tables but I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\jont\Documents\ATP\Webapp>manage.py syncdb
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\admin_tools\utils.py:9: RemovedInDjango19Warning:      
django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
from django.utils.importlib import import_module

c:\users\jont\documents\django-trunk\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py:148:  
RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't de
her isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was  
loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
class ContentType(models.Model):

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\admin_tools\dashboard\modules.py:8: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The 
django.forms.util module has been renamed. Use django.forms.utils instead.
from django.forms.util import flatatt

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\tables.py:171: RemovedInDjango19Warning: SortedDict
is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. attrs["base_columns"] =  
SortedDict(parent_columns)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\tables.py:193: RemovedInDjango19Warning: SortedDict 
is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
attrs["base_columns"].update(SortedDict(cols))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jont\Documents\ATP\Webapp\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "c:\users\jont\documents\django-trunk\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 336, in
execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "c:\users\jont\documents\django-trunk\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 310, in 
execute
django.setup()
File "c:\users\jont\documents\django-trunk\django\__init__.py", line 23, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "c:\users\jont\documents\django-trunk\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
app_config.ready()
File "c:\users\jont\documents\django-trunk\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 22, in ready
self.module.autodiscover()
File "c:\users\jont\documents\django-trunk\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24, in  
autodiscover
autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
File "c:\users\jont\documents\django-trunk\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 73, in 
autodiscover_modules
import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Users\jont\Documents\ATP\Webapp\jobs\admin.py", line 4, in <module>
from jobs.views import registration
File "C:\Users\jont\Documents\ATP\Webapp\jobs\views.py", line 12, in <module>
from jobs.forms import ApplicantForm, JobForm, \
File "C:\Users\jont\Documents\ATP\Webapp\jobs\forms.py", line 8, in <module>
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
File "c:\users\jont\documents\django-trunk\django\forms\models.py", line 272, in __new__
"needs updating." % name
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields'   attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form JobForm needs updating.

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form JobForm needs updating.
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Like the error mentions, you need to **explicitly** specify the fields, or exclude.

Try this

```
class JobForm(models.ModelForm):
    #fields

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = "__all__"
```

which would include all the fields

Here is the relevant [documentation (release notes 1.6)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#modelform-without-fields-or-exclude)

> Previously, if you wanted a ModelForm to use all fields on the model,
>   you could simply omit the Meta.fields attribute, and all fields would
>   be used.
>
> This can lead to security problems where fields are added to the model
>   and, unintentionally, automatically become editable by end users. In
>   some cases, particular with boolean fields, it is possible for this
>   problem to be completely invisible. This is a form of Mass assignment
>   vulnerability.
>
> For this reason, this behavior is deprecated, and using the
>   Meta.exclude option is strongly discouraged. Instead, all fields that
>   are intended for inclusion in the form should be listed explicitly in
>   the fields attribute.
>
> If this security concern really does not apply in your case, there is
>   a shortcut to explicitly indicate that all fields should be used - use
>   the special value "`__all__`" for the fields attribute

Comment: Thank you @karthikr, I will check that out. However, for now, reverting to Django 1.7 seemed to fix the problem. I expect there are a few changes that need to be made to my code if I were to go to 1.8

Comment: It seems like this raises an exception for django 1.8. It just throws a warning in django 1.7, for which it might be worth updating the modelforms anyway..

Comment: `fields="__all__"` is also required as a parameter for `inlineformset_factory()`

Answer (score 5):

You can set fields or exclude in the ModelForm in Django 1.7.
It changes in 1.8, you should set fields or exclude in the Meta class within ModelForm.

```
class JobForm(models.ModelForm):
#fields

class Meta:
    model = Job
    fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I set **"Meta" inner class** without **"fields" or "exclude" attributes** in **"NewUserForm(UserCreationForm)" class** in **"account/forms.py"** to create a form as shown below:

```py
# "account/forms.py"

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  class Meta: # Here
    model = User
```

So, I added **"fields" attribute** to **"Meta" inner class** as shown below:

```py
# "account/forms.py"

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  class Meta: # Here
    model = User
    fields = ("username",) # Here
```

Or, added **"exclude" attribute** to **"Meta" inner class** as shown below:

```py
# "account/forms.py"

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  class Meta: # Here
    model = User
    exclude = ("first_name", "last_name") # Here
```

Then, I could solve the error.

Answer (score -6):

Dropping to Django 1.7 seemed to do the trick. There didn't seem to be an easy way to adapt the code to fit Django 1.8.

Comment: There are other answer above which helps. Instead of verifying your own answer please do verify the correct answer so that it would be helpful to others as well.